# ConfigurationManager doesnt recognize my connection string

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-string

I'm trying to do a `DropdownList` from Database using ASP.Net Web Form.

**Page_Load:**

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OraDbContext"].ConnectionString;
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT NOMPRE FROM HOPEMPL", conn); //HOPEMPL@HQ
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            oda.Fill(ds);
            DDnompre.DataSource = ds;
            DDnompre.DataTextField = "NOMPRE";
            DDnompre.DataValueField = "NOMPRE";
            DDnompre.DataBind();

        }
```

**Connection String:**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OraDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe;DBA PRIVILEGE=;PASSWORD=1234;USER ID=LOUG&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Error:**

> "System.ArgumentException : ''metadata'  is not a valid connection
>   string attribute' "

I'm also working with a database first (EF)

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
 <add name="{ConnectionName}" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" 
        providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

Comment: It worked but i can't access database now it says invalid username or password and i'm not mistaken them...